# SQL Server - joining 3 tables and updating flag

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Currently a stored procedure that I have creates 3 tables based on which source table the data comes from (S1, S2, S3). While doing so it using a ranking function to rank each record based on a product number and date.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.ProductNumber, 
    CAST(CASE 
            WHEN b.ProductNumber = b.NewProductNumber) 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
         END AS BIT) 'NewProduct', 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY Date) 'RowNum'
INTO 
    Table1
FROM 
    Table2 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    Table3 b ON a.ID = b.ID and b.Source = 'S1'

SELECT 
    a.*, b.ProductNumber, 
    CAST(CASE 
            WHEN b.ProductNumber = b.NewProductNumber)  
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
         END AS BIT) 'NewProduct', 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY Date) 'RowNum'
INTO 
    Table1
FROM 
    Table2 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table3 b ON a.ID = b.ID and b.Source = 'S2'

SELECT 
    a.*, b.ProductNumber, 
    CAST(CASE 
            WHEN b.ProductNumber = b.NewProductNumber) 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
         END AS BIT) 'NewProduct', 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY Date) 'RowNum'
INTO 
    Table1
FROM 
    Table2 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table3 b ON a.ID = b.ID and b.Source = 'S3'
```

It then pools this data into one Collective table and updates the 'NewProduct' Flag based on 'RowNum'

```
SELECT 
    ProductNumber, NewProductNumber, 
    CAST('Source1' AS VARCHAR(15)) 'SourceName',  
    NewProduct, RowNum
INTO 
    CollectiveTable
FROM 
    Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ProductNumber, NewProductNumber, 
    CAST('Source2' AS VARCHAR(15)),      
    NewProduct, RowNum
FROM
    Table2

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ProductNumber, NewProductNumber, 
    CAST('Source3' AS VARCHAR(15)),      
    NewProduct, RowNum
FROM 
    Table3;

UPDATE CollectiveTable
SET NewProduct = 0
WHERE NewProduct = 1
  AND RowNum != 1;
```

My question is, in the `CollectiveTable`, if I end up with records from multiple sources that are the same product and flagged as "New Products", I want the original source to be the only one marked as "New", how would I do this.

I really don't want to use a cursor for this.

For example,

CollectiveTable

```
ProductNumber   NewProductNumber    SourceName      NewProduct      RowNum
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
99999           99999               Source1         1               1
99999           99999               Source2         1               1
99999           99999               Source3         1               1
00000           00000               Source2         1               1
00000           00000               Source1         1               1
12345           12345               Source3         1               1
12345           12345               Source2         1               1
```

For Product 99999 the "Original Source" would be Source1, 00000 Source1, & 12345 Source2

Therefore, I want to update the "NewProduct" flags for the following records as so:

```
ProductNumber   NewProductNumber    SourceName      NewProduct      RowNum
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
99999           99999               Source1         1               1
99999           99999               Source2         0               1
99999           99999               Source3         0               1
00000           00000               Source2         0               1
00000           00000               Source1         1               1
12345           12345               Source3         0               1
12345           12345               Source2         1               1
```

What is a good way to go about this.  Thank you so much in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are *Sources* really numerically increasing like that? How do you really determine *original source*?

Comment: You can't "SELECT INTO" the same table name twice in a single batch, you'd throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to help us understand the problem and experiment with solutions, may I suggest adding code for table definitions and sample records, not necessarily 100% accurate or complex, just enough to correlate with.

Second, I'm basing my answer on *several* assumptions, some of which are:

- You don't mind the inefficiency of correcting the flags **after** your usual workload is done.
- You have only 3 sources.

Lastly, this surely have so much potential for improvement, if not outright bested by other approaches:

```
-- Correct flags of any record that should be corrected due to presence of Source1.
UPDATE C2C3
SET NewProduct = 0
FROM CollectiveTable AS C2C3
INNER JOIN CollectiveTable AS C1 ON C2C3.ProductNumber = C1.ProductNumber AND C1.SourceName = 'SOURCE1'
WHERE C2C3.SourceName IN ('Source2', 'Source3')

-- Correct flags of Source3 records who weren't corrected by previous step.
UPDATE C3
SET NewProduct = 0
FROM CollectiveTable AS C3
INNER JOIN CollectiveTable AS C1C2 ON C1C2.ProductNumber = C3.ProductNumber AND C1C2.SourceName IN ('SOURCE1', 'SOURCE2')
WHERE C3.SourceName IN ('Source3')
```